# ¿Puedo conectarme a mi proyecto wordpress directamente con Filezilla o necesito contratar una empresa de hosting aparte (ej. cPanel)?

Tags: wordpress, filezilla

tengo un sitio desarrollado con Wordpress, pero necesito trabajar en la carpeta wp-admin y para eso según estuve leyendo necesito descargarlo en mi pc local y luego subir los archivos actualizados por FTP. Para eso me descargue el Filezilla, pero no logro acceder a mi proyecto Wordpress para descargarlo ya que no tengo las credenciales de acceso al servidor y no se de donde sacarlas. Es posible esto? o requiero de un espacio en un servidor por ejemplo cPanel para poder hacerlo?

Comment: Te recomiendo que si tienes un panel de adminsitracion(que supongo que tengas) en tu hosting busques el apartado de FTP , ahi suele haber un usuario por defecto para conectarte, si no es asi ponte en conctacto con el servicio de soporte de tu hosting

Comment: Las credenciales que tienes deben ser tu direccion web, un usuario y una clave con eso mas que suficiente para conectarte desde tu cliente filezilla y hacer las descargas o subidas de archivos a tu web.

Answer (score -1):

Si necesitas respaldar el contenido de tu sitio web de manera rápida sin esperar a que te den las credenciales desde el dashboard (wp-admin), ve a plugins->añadir nuevo y en el buscador coloca gestor de archivos, te va instalar como una interfaz de la cual veras las carpetas ya solo seria comprimirla a través del mismo plugin y descargarla desde el mismo y ya esta